# Excessive physical memory used on our Oracle 11.2.0.4 database servers running on RedHat 6

Tags: oracle, memory

This is my first post on Stackoverflow so please be gentle. Basically on our  live database servers I am seeing excessive physical memory being used. Even after upgrading the memory

We recently had a memory shortage issue on our live database server which effected the operation of the database, the live server had 8GB of physical memory. 8GB in  hindsight was too low so we upgrade to 16GB straight away all the 16GB was reported as being used on top and free -m. We then upgrade the memory again, again all the memory was used as reported in top and free -m

The current output on top, free -m and dstat -m show :

Tasks: 608 total,   2 running, 602 sleeping,   0 stopped,   4 zombie
Cpu(s): 18.1%us,  1.5%sy,  0.0%ni, 78.9%id,  1.4%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.1%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  32872264k total, 32449036k used,   423228k free,   172064k buffers
Swap:  6291444k total,  1284776k used,  5006668k free, 25308944k cached

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
42754 mislve    20   0 12.8g 542m 535m R 93.8  1.7   4:37.94 oracle
43278 mislve    20   0 12.8g 1.3g 1.3g S  7.8  4.0   0:28.44 oracle
23227 mislve    20   0 12.8g 159m 155m S  3.9  0.5   0:06.54 oracle
 5120 mislve    -2   0 12.8g  14m  14m S  2.0  0.0  46:55.13 oracle
 5130 mislve    20   0 12.9g  96m  84m S  2.0  0.3  27:25.16 oracle
 5136 mislve    20   0 12.9g 239m 238m S  2.0  0.7   6:32.02 oracle
10428 mislve    20   0 12.8g 1.4g 1.4g S  2.0  4.6   0:36.53 oracle

lln1p-band01:mislve$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         32101      31860        241      10222        167      24874
-/+ buffers/cache:       6819      25282
Swap:         6143       1254       4889

lln1p-band01:mislve$ dstat -m
------memory-usage-----
 used  buff  cach  free
6825M  167M 24.3G  233M
6825M  167M 24.3G  232M
6825M  167M 24.3G  232M
6825M  167M 24.3G  232M
6826M  167M 24.3G  231M^C

The size of the database sga is currently 13.463GB

SQL> show sga

Total System Global Area 1.3463E+10 bytes
Fixed Size                  2281432 bytes
Variable Size            6912213032 bytes
Database Buffers         6308233216 bytes
Redo Buffers              240676864 bytes

Rightly or wrongly I configured the database to use Automatic Memory Management (AMM) as for a temporary measure we wanted to see if we tried to ring fence the memory used by the Oracle database would it stop the excessive use of RAM. So I set the  memory_max_target to 16GB and memory_max_target to 14GB. I know these values are excessive and I probably should not used AMM on a live OLTP system so I will be disabling it and rizing the SGA and PGA accordingly.

SQL> show parameter target

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE

---

archive_lag_target                   integer     0
db_flashback_retention_target        integer     1440
fast_start_io_target                 integer     0
fast_start_mttr_target               integer     300
memory_max_target                    big integer 16G
memory_target                        big integer 14G
parallel_servers_target              integer     64
pga_aggregate_target                 big integer 1500000000
sga_target                           big integer 0

But even with a ring fence of 14GB we are seeing almost all the RAMn being used. I suspect the memory is being used in the operating system file cache. Another theory is that the Oracle session memory is not being released back to the operating system due to a database server leak.

I did run:  sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches   to try and clear the page cache but had made any impact on the memory usage

Here is the detail memory for the server :

lln1p-band01:mislve$  cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:       32872264 kB
MemFree:          423780 kB
Buffers:          185776 kB
Cached:         25300460 kB
SwapCached:        48340 kB
Active:         18999184 kB
Inactive:        9041360 kB
Active(anon):   11505660 kB
Inactive(anon):  1514952 kB
Active(file):    7493524 kB
Inactive(file):  7526408 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       6291444 kB
SwapFree:        5002792 kB
Dirty:                72 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       2509516 kB
Mapped:          9673360 kB
Shmem:          10466304 kB
Slab:             605716 kB
SReclaimable:     394984 kB
SUnreclaim:       210732 kB
KernelStack:       12736 kB
PageTables:      3517352 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    22727576 kB
Committed_AS:   17502452 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      218536 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359505336 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:   1079296 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:        8192 kB
DirectMap2M:     2088960 kB
DirectMap1G:    31457280 kB

The version on our RedHat operating system is : 2.6.32-696.3.2.el6.x86_64
the version of our Oracle database is : Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

Has anyone experienced anything similar or know what could be causing the high memory usage and how to remedy the issue.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: Also here is the detailed memory information for the server :

Comment: How many oracle processes (users and background) are going to run on that server? What is current memory size?

Comment: Hi sandman,    our live server has 32GB of physical memory, there are currently 287 database sessions running on the server. The PGA is currently using about a 1GB of memory :

Comment: Also there are 286 approx users - database connection processes and 
45  background processes running